# codeigniter pagination doesn't change data on view

Tags: php, codeigniter, pagination

I am having troubles working with pagination of CI.
How come that the data on the view doesn't change?

View:

```
<section class = "home">
<table>
    <?php foreach($players as $p): ?>
        <tr><td><?php echo $p->uname; ?></td><td><?php echo $p->ufbid; ?></td><td><?php echo $p->uemail; ?></td><td><?php echo $p->umobile; ?></td><td><?php echo $p->points; ?></td><td><?php echo $p->pticks; ?></td></tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    <tr><?php echo $link; ?></tr>
</table>
```

Controller:

```
$perPage = 20;
    $pageConf = array(
        'base_url' => site_url('home/'),
        'total_rows' => $this->home_model->countPlayers(),
        'per_page' => $perPage,
        'uri_segment' => 2,
        //'use_page_numbers' =>TRUE,
    );

    $this->pagination->initialize($pageConf);
    $offset = $this->uri->segment(3) ? $this->uri->segment(3) : 0;
    $pData = $this->home_model->displayPlayers($perPage,$offset);
    $data = array(
        'players'=> $pData,
        'content'=> 'home',
        'link' => $this->pagination->create_links() 
    );
    $this->load->view('template/template',$data);
```

I already loaded the libraries in my constructor method.

The set of records from the controller doesn't change. My uri segment 3 is like this `&per_page=40`.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code,may be it help you If you are using Pagination Class of 
CodeIgniter.

```
 $perPage = 20;
 $pageConf = array(
    'base_url' => site_url('home/'),
    'total_rows' => $this->home_model->countPlayers(),
    'per_page' => $perPage,
    **'uri_segment' => 3,**
    //'use_page_numbers' =>TRUE,
 );
     $this->pagination->initialize($pageConf);
     $offset = $this->uri->segment(3) ? $this->uri->segment(3) : 0;
     $pData = $this->home_model->displayPlayers($perPage,$offset);
    $data = array(
    'players'=> $pData,
    'content'=> 'home',
    'link' => $this->pagination->create_links() 
    );
   $this->load->view('template/template',$data);
```